# Pug y NODEJs. No se muestra imagen al importarla desde BD mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, pug

Tengo este código

```
each movieseries in data    
       img.poster(src=movieseries.poster alt=movieseries.title)
```

cuando lo veo con el inspector de google se muestra

```
<img class="poster" src="./public/img/Batman_X300.jpg" alt="Batman">
```

Revise la ruta de la imagen, pero igual no se muestra la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Buscando otras respuestas me conseguí, que como en mi app.js, tengo declarada una variable llamada publicDir

```
publicDir = express.static(`${__dirname}/public`)
```

y mi carpeta img está en la carpeta public, "las rutas de los archivos estáticos deberían comenzar con "/" y luego escribir la ruta tal como está en mi carpeta pública. p.e. como la imagen está en public/img; luego en la BD debo registrar como valor de la rutas de la imágenes, /img/laimage.jpg; en mi caso p.e: /img/Batman_X300.jpg.
Esta solución la conseguí en el siguiente enlace:
[1]: https://living-sun.com/es/nodejs/590828-cant-display-static-image-in-jade-nodejs-express-pug.html

Gracias